# Associating child tag data with grandparent tag using CFC-based custom tags

Tags: cfml, lucee, cfimport

The full repro case for this question is in my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/daccfml/scratch/tree/master/blogExamples/cfml/customtags/nested/3). I'll only reproduce the necessary bits here.

Let's say I have this usage of some custom tags:

```
<!--- testCfcTags.cfm --->
<cfimport taglib="cfcBasedTags" prefix="t">

Text before tags<br>
<t:grandparent gp:attr="set in grandparent">
    Text in grandparent, before parent<br>
    <t:parent p:attr="set in parent">
        Text in parent, before child<br>
        <t:child c:attr="set in child">
            Text in child<br>
        </t:child>
        Text in parent, after child<br>
    </t:parent>
    Text in grandparent, after parent<br>
</t:grandparent>
Text after tags<br>
```

If I was using CFM-based custom tags, and I was to want to associate data from within my implementation of the `child` tag with the `grandparent` tag, I would simply to this:

```
<!--- child.cfm --->
<cfif thistag.executionMode eq "end">
    <cfassociate basetag="cf_grandparent" datacollection="childAttributesForGrandparent"><!--- this line --->
    <cfassociate basetag="cf_parent" datacollection="childAttributesForParent">
</cfif>
```

Note I can associate directly to the grandparent tag.

I cannot work out how to do this *cleanly* with Lucee's CFC-based custom tags.

This is the best I can come up with:

```
// Child.cfc
component {

    function init(hasEndTag, parent){
        this.parent = arguments.parent;
    }

    function onEndTag(attributes, caller, generatedContent){
        writeOutput(generatedContent);
        this.parent.childattributesForParent = attributes;
        this.parent.parent.childattributesForGrandparent = attributes;
        return false;
    }

}
```

And in Parent.cfc I have this:

```
// Parent.cfc
component {

    function init(hasEndTag, parent){
        this.parent = arguments.parent;
    }

    function onEndTag(attributes, caller, generatedContent){
        writeOutput(generatedContent);
        this.parent.parentattributesForGrandparent = attributes;
        writeDump(var=this.childAttributesForParent, label="Parent childAttributesForParent");
        return false;
    }

}
```

That cumulative (mis-)usage of the `this` scope of Parent and Grandparent means from Child I can bung stuff straight into the Grandparent via `this.parent.parent`.

However that's all a bit "[Heath Robinson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._Heath_Robinson)". Given the rest of Lucee's CFC-based custom tag implementation is pretty slick, I am sure I'm just missing something. I really don't think I ought to have to burrow through the Parent to get to the Grandparent. Also it means that the code would need to differ for situations in which the Child is directly within the Grandparent. What I really need is for some tag-hierarchy to be passed between CFCs, not simply the parent.

I've googled about, but most of what's out there is written by me (which is in turn based on the blog articles originally written for Railo's implementation of this - which is what the Lucee implementation is based on).

Docs I've already read, which are no help:

- [Railo: CFC-based custom tags](http://blog.adamcameron.me/2014/08/railo-cfc-based-custom-tags.html)
- [CFC-based Custom Tags by Example - Part 1](http://blog.getrailo.com/post.cfm/cfc-based-custom-tags-by-example-part-1)
- [CFC-based Custom Tags by Example - Part 2](http://blog.getrailo.com/post.cfm/cfc-based-custom-tags-by-example-part-2)
- [CFC-based Custom Tags by Example - Part 3](http://blog.getrailo.com/post.cfm/cfc-based-custom-tags-by-example-part-3)

Comment: Is it worth tagging this as coldfusion and railo too... those who are maybe using lucee but not following the tag yet might miss this?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Railo blog:

http://blog.getrailo.com/post.cfm/cfc-based-custom-tags-by-example-part-1

> You can use the tag cfassociate and the function GetBaseTagList and >GetBaseTagData the same way as for regular CFML based custom tags.

So you can do (in cfscript):

```
cfassociate(basetag="cf_grandparent", datacollection="childAttributesForGrandparent");
```

I've thrown together a gist with some samples - I've tested and verified it works on Lucee 4.5.1:
https://gist.github.com/dajester2013/183e862915972d51279f

### Edit: Option 2, base tag approach:

Based on my comment, here is a potential approach via base tag - it at leasts masks the not-so-pretty aspects:

BaseTag.cfc

```
component accessors=true {

    property name="tagName";
    property name="parent";
    property name="hasEndTag";

    public BaseTag function init() {
        structAppend(variables, arguments);

        tagName = "cf_" & lcase(listLast(getMetaData(this).fullname,"."));

        return this;
    }

    public any function getParent(string tagName, ancestors=1) {
        if (!isNull(tagName)) {

            var data = getBaseTagData(tagName, ancestors);
            if (structKeyExists(data,"thisTag")) {
                return data.thisTag;

            // getBaseTagData returns the variables scope for CFC tags...
            } else if (structKeyExists(data, "this")) {
                return data.this;
            }
        } else if (!isNull(variables.parent)) {
            return variables.parent;
        }
    }

    private void function associate(required string tagName, string dataCollection=this.getTagName()) {
        cfassociate(basetag=tagname, dataCollection=dataCollection);
    }

}
```

TestChild.cfc

```
component extends=BaseTag {

    public function onStartTag() {
        attributes._childId = randrange(1000,9000);
        associate("cf_testtag", "testchildren");

        writedump(var=this.getParent(),label='immediateparent');
        writedump(var=this.getParent("cf_testtag"), label='testtag');
        abort;
    }

}
```

Comment: Cheers, but yeah, I know that (I link to the same article above). But that's kinda "in spite" of the CFC-based approach to the issue, not in-complement to it. If you read the next sentence in the article "These features are not really easy to use, so we looked for another way of interaction between tags" Micha kinda alludes to the idea that using `<cfassociate>` is not the preferred way to do this sort of thing with CFC-based custom tags. However doesn't go on to say how one *should* do this via another mechanism. I suspect they have simply overlooked it.

Comment: Another option would be to implement a base component you extend all your tags from.  Inside that base component you would define some accessor methods.  I'm thinking something along the lines of ExtJS's component selectors: `this.up("tag_name");`